# crear exe con pyinstaller incluyendo subcarpetas

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Tengo un proyecto hecho en Python 3.4.

Quiero hacer el ejecutable incluyendo las sub-carpetas que tiene el proyecto, pero al ejecutar:

```
pyinstaller --noconsole main.py
```

no me agrega dichas subcarpetas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya esta, ya lo he conseguido.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None
added_files=[('./data/*.*','data'),('./ui/*.*','ui')]

a = Analysis(['main_gia.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\tasl\\Documents\\bitbucket\\gia_python'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=added_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
        a.scripts,
        exclude_binaries=True,
        name='main_gia',
        debug=False,
        strip=False,
        upx=True,
        console=False,
        icon='./data/icon_gia.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='main_gia',
               icon='./data/icon_gia.ico')
```

Con COLLECT.

Answer (score 0):

Por línea de comandos no se puede. Lo que se tiene que hacer es crear un archivo de "especificación" del proceso de congelado, por ej. main.spec. De hecho, tal vez ni tengas que crearlo ya que el propio pyinstaller crea uno por defecto con el cual realiza el proceso (cuidado si lo modificas porque así como lo ejecutás lo va a crear siempre destruyendo cualquier cambio que hagas).

Para correr el proceso a partir del archivo de especificación hay que pasarle como parámetro dicho archivo: `pyinstaller --noconsole main.spec`. En este archivo o más bien script python, tenés mucho mayor control sobre el proceso, y podés establecer que carpetas y/o archivos agregar. Hay que inicializar una clase Analysis con algunas de las opciones que necesitás, por ejemplo:

```
a = Analysis(...
 datas= [ ('/mygame/sfx/*.mp3', 'sfx' ) ],
 ...
 )
```

Lo que se está haciendo es incluir todos los archivo *.mp3 de una carpeta específica y en el runtime final irán a parar a una carpeta "sfx". Para mayor información te recomiendo consultar [aquí](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html).

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta pero tal y como tengo mi .spec me crea un solo exe, necesito que me cree la carpeta de dist con todos los archivos, Sabrías como?

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema tratando de crear el instalador de mi chatbot, que usa embedding de llama-index y la API de OpenAI y estuve dando vueltas tres dias completos 20 horas diarias, hasta que gracias a DIOS, y a ChatGTP, y BingChat, logré una solución efectiva, logré crear mi ejecutable y ya me funciona  perfectamente para este caso y es la siguiente:

**Nota**
No puedes usar pyinstaller myscript.py
Asegúrate de tener la ultima version de llama-index y de todos tus paquetes,
puedes ejecutar este comando y lo mismo para todos tus paquetes

```
  pip install --upgrade llama-index
```

**Solución**

- Configura un archivo myscript.spec, sigue estos pasos:
  siguiente instrucción:
- Asegúrate de tener pyinstaller instalado en tu entorno virtual.
  Si no lo tienes instalado, ejecuta el siguiente comando para
  instalarlo:
  `pip install pyinstaller`
- Abre una terminal y navega hasta la ubicación de tu script de Python.
  Ejecuta el siguiente comando para generar el archivo .spec:
  `pyinstaller --name nombre_de_tu_aplicacion --onefile tu_script.py`

  Asegúrate de reemplazar nombre_de_tu_aplicacion con el nombre deseado para tu
  aplicación y tu_script.py con el nombre de tu script de Python.
- Después de ejecutar el comando, se generará un archivo .spec en la misma
  ubicación donde se encuentra tu script de Python.

  El archivo .spec es un archivo de configuración de PyInstaller que especifica
  cómo se debe construir el ejecutable de tu aplicación. Puedes abrir el
  archivo .spec con un editor de texto para personalizar la configuración si es
  necesario.
  Una vez que hayas generado el archivo .spec, puedes usarlo para construir el
  ejecutable de tu aplicación ejecutando el siguiente comando:

  ```
       pyinstaller myscript.py --hidden-import=tiktoken_ext.openai_public -- 
       hidden-import=tiktoken_ext
  ```

**Explicación**
Se usa el argumento --hidden-import para forzar a PyInstaller a incluir tiktoken_ext.openai_public y tiktoken_ext en el ejecutable que está generando. Esto puede ser necesario cuando PyInstaller no puede detectar automáticamente todas las dependencias de un script.

Esta solución puede ayudar a otros programadores que encuentren un error similar al utilizar PyInstaller, especialmente si están utilizando módulos o paquetes similares en sus scripts. Sin embargo, este consejo podría no aplicarse a todas las situaciones de error similares, ya que la causa exacta del error puede variar dependiendo del script y el entorno.

Recuerda que es importante entender por qué se esta utilizando un comando particular antes de implementarlo, para evitar problemas potenciales más adelante. En este caso, es importante comprender por qué estos módulos estaban ocultos y cómo su inclusión ayuda a solucionar el problema. Es posible que este problema se haya resuelto al incluir estos módulos porque eran dependencias necesarias para mi script que PyInstaller no pudo detectar automáticamente.

Además, el comando que proporcionado asume que los módulos tiktoken_ext.openai_public y tiktoken_ext están instalados y disponibles en tu entorno Python. Si no lo están, es posible que debas instalarlos usando pip o un método similar

Este es mi caso particular, pero mas o menos así debe quedar tu mycript.spec

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['chatne.py'],
    pathex=['C:\\Users\\user\\source\\repos\\chatne'],
    binaries=[],
        datas=[
        ('templates', 'templates'), 
        ('public', 'public'),
        ('static', 'static'),        
        ('llama_index', 'llama_index'),
        ('langchain/chains/llm_summarization_checker/prompts', 'langchain/chains/llm_summarization_checker/prompts'),
        ('storage/storage1', 'storage/storage1'),
    ],
    hiddenimports=['tiktoken_ext.openai_public', 'tiktoken_ext'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='chatne',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='chatne',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrega el comando `--add-data` a la hora de crear el ejecutable

```
pyinstaller --windowed --add-data "nombre_carpeta;nombre_carpeta" script.py
```

Por cada carpeta tienes que agregar el `--add-data` antes (has esto si las carpetas no están dentro de la primera carpeta que añades, pero si todo está dentro de esa carpeta no es necesario añadir nada más)